# Using Python with the Twitter API to post tweets?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Anyone have any reccomendations as to what python library to use to post tweets to twitter?

The ones I've found are

- twython
- PythonTwitter
- TwitterAPI
- Python Twitter Tools
- Tweepy
- TweetPony
- twitter-gobject

Anyone else know of any good/better ones or can anyone give me a simple example to post to twitter?

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Answer (score 12):

[Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) is pretty nice and is constantly updated. After the setup steps, using it is as easy as:

```
from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter.update_status(status='See how easy using Twython is!')
```

Comment: Oh wow that is easy, may I also inquire as to how one would get the oauth token/oauth token secret?

Comment: You will need to register your app on https://dev.twitter.com/apps to get the token/secret. If you look at the Twython link in my answer, the process for doing this is explained really well!

Comment: I get `Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token`

Comment: I can't even find where to setup user/pass for a twitter to post from :S

Comment: What if I want to post on behalf of another username ??